# 2 вопроса с rnd

Tags: база-данных

Знатоки, интересует механика, не голый код. Необходимо:

1. из 3-х баз рандомно вывести имя#, фамилия#, фото(№ в базе);
2. при выборе созданного персонажа эти 3 показателя объединить в одну переменную что ли.

Comment: К сожалению, здесь нет "механики", а только "голый код" `SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY RAND()`

Comment: up^^: SELECT column FROM table WHERE ROWNUM <= 3 ORDER BY RAND()

Comment: p.s. это над чем нужно работать чтоб была необходимость выбирать (случайным образом!!!) пользователей из трех разных баз данных?

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, что Вас интересует. Из каких баз? Из баз или из таблиц базы? На каком языке реализация, в конце концов?

А если иди по принципу "как спросил так и ответил":

1. в приложении создать 3 целочисленных переменных, которым присваивать рандомные значения, и сделать запросы на выборку полей по ключам, равным этим переменным;
2. создать некую структуру (struct, record) - смотря на чем написано, либо вообще создать класс, в которой создать поля с нужными "характеристиками"; создать переменную типа созданной структуры или класса и работать с ней.

Ну как-то так. )

Comment: спасибо помогло